# StartSonar.bat does not start

Tags: sonarqube

I am trying to run sonarqube but the console is empty[image]

I tried debugging the script and the function *check_if_sonar_is_running* runs without errors . However, the rest of the script does not execute. The interesting thing is that this script works on my other computer. I have installed java 11.

StartSonar script below

[image]

Does anyone have any idea what could have gone wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is add environment variables. In system variables: I added path to java bin. In user variables I added variable "JAVA_HOME" to main catalog of java. Restart PC and sonarqube started.